# How can i set my new ip adress? [Debian / Ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu, ip, vps, linux-networking, ovh

I have my own VPS at OVH and it comes with a default
ip address in France. So for geolocation needs, i bought one 
for in the UK. Now i have Ubuntu server 16.40 running, and i want to 
set my newly bought ip address as the default. Any clues on how to do this?

(yes im starting, want to learn this)

Google results does only give a 'failover' but i want it as default. 
Can you guys help me a bit on this one

Comment: Serverfault is for professional sysadmins sorry, we tend to know our 'ABC's and why this won't 'just work'.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have bought the address from OVH and they told you that you would be able to use it for the server in France (which is extremely unlikely), this will not work.

In general, IP addresses, unlike domain names, are bound to physical networks and you can't just randomly assign an address to some host in a totally different network.

Please read up on the fundamentals on TCP/IP networking to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just randomly assigned an IP address from somewhere else to your server and hope it'll work (well, you can, but your hope will be in vain).

In order for a packet assigned to that IP to reach your server, some routing configuration needs to be done. Your options are:

- Have a machine in the UK behind the router where the network thinks your IP is, which tunnels everything into a VPN or some such to your server in France. This will be slow, as everything gets routed twice (once to France, once to the UK). It also requires you to have some device there.
- Have whoever sold you the IP do some BGP magic so it gets routed to France. They probably won't want to do that. It will also be visible for people outside their network, which means that eventually the GeoIP information will be changed and be listed as 'in France', which I guess defeats the purpose.
- Stop using your server in France, and use a server in the UK instead. After all, if you want things to appear as though they come from the UK, it helps if that's actually the case...

Comment: Thank-you so much wouter, you are a great help.
Dank u wel!